# wifi issue on ubuntu 20.04. i cant load web pages when connected to wifi wirelessly

Tags: networking

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 and, when I tether to a mobile phone via WiFi, it connects and loads pages. But when I connect to my home WiFi router, it shows as being connected but never loads pages. There is an error that says: "Secure connection failed or other error in reaching the page".

If i am connected via ethernet, pages load very fast but there's nothing over WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the drivers of your network card. If you cannot, uninstall it and reinstall the latest. There might be an updated fix to the latest version of the driver which did not get updated when you upgraded to 20.04. I upgraded yesterday to 20.04, and I was fighting with the same problem the whole day. Uninstall and reinstall worked for me. If you do it too, when installing it again, make sure to set it in non-concurrent mode (the source page should tell you how to do so), otherwise the wifi card will show twice and you will keep having the same problem.